# Encoding and decoding ethernet

Tags: ethernet

Is there a way to encode the data sent over 4 ethernet cables into one cable and then decode them back to 4 cables?
I'm trying to send many ethernet cables over a long distance on one cable and then getting back the 4 cables.

The application I'm working on forces me to get the cables back because I have some converted USB signals that I need to convert back to USB after receiving the Ethernet signal.

Comment: I'd say this is not about *Ethernet*. You are using twisted pair cables and want to multiplex the arbitrary signals of the USB range extenders. I guess, it's bad luck. Maybe there are USB extenders that support multiple devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for then you could do the following:

Create 4 different vlans in two different switches trunk them over the one cable that you have available.

Architecture would look like:

---4 Ethernet connections - switch(A) with 4 vlans - single Ethernet trunk connection - switch(B) with same 4 vlans - 4 Ethernet connections ---